# how to merge two different array in php with out chage array key

Tags: php

I have two different array how to get below out put.
Array One:-

```
[81799] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL_HITS] => 254
            [UNIQUE_HITS] => 82
        )
```

Array Two:-

```
[81799] => Array
        (
            [ACTIVATION] => 7561.60
            [RENEWAL] => 300
            [ACT_REVENUE] => 7310.22
        )
```

Expected output:-

```
[81799] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL_HITS] => 254
            [UNIQUE_HITS] => 82
            [ACTIVATION] => 7561.60
            [RENEWAL] => 300
            [ACT_REVENUE] => 7310.22
        )
```

Comment: DID you try anything???

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It seems that every third question on PHP is about merging array contents...

Comment: did you try `array_merge` ?

Comment: i tried array_merge , array_combine & array1+array2

Comment: did u checked the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

I guess your array looks like below:

```
<?php
$a1 = array("81799" => array("TOTAL_HITS" => 254, "UNIQUE_HITS" => 82));
$a2 = array("81799" => array("ACTIVATION" => 7561.60, "RENEWAL" => 300, "ACT_REVENUE" => 7310.22));

foreach($a1 as $key => $val) {
   $result[$key] = array_merge($a1[$key], $a2[$key]);
}    

print_r($result);
```

Comment: and what about `81799` key?

Comment: @devpro I just had a simple example to show, how it should work.

Comment: my comment is just related to this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39741371/revisions .. well now this will work as expected .

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding me devpro, I have just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$a = array("81799" => Array
            (
            "TOTAL_HITS" => 254,
           "UNIQUE_HITS" => 82
            )
           );
$b = array("81799" => Array
            (
            "ACTIVATION" => 7561.60,
            "RENEWAL" => 300,
            "ACT_REVENUE" => 7310.22
            )
           );
foreach($a as $key_a => $val_a)
{
    $temp = $b[$key_a] + $val_a;
    //$result[$key_a] = $b[$key_a];
    $result[$key_a] =  $temp;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Bo0lv)**